# Clarification on potential due to uniform line of charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

I was reading a little about electrostatics when i got stuck with a derivation.

Consider an infinitely long conductor exrending to both side . Take two points at distances $a,and b:b>a$  then the potential difference

$v_b-v_a=\int_{a}^{b}-Edr$

=$\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dr}{r}$

=$\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon} ln(\frac{b}{a})$

my doubt is where did the minus sign go in the original $-Edr$ shouldnt it be

$\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon} ln(\frac{a}{b})$

please correct me

Comment: You tell us.  Try factoring the negative sign out of the integral.  With a positive λ, the potential should decrease as you go out.

Comment: @R.W.Bird i dont understand what you mean,,, is the proof correct?

Comment: Your first equation has a negative sign inside the integral. Where did it go?  E is positive in the direction of dr

Comment: @R.W.Bird  exactly, but this was the proof given in a book. Is it wrong

Comment: Actually, if its just a long conductor, there is no net charge, no field and no potential difference.  If it is a line of negative charge of linear density λ, then the field points in, and the potential increases as you go out.